# React Router 2 more efficient routing

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I am using a project I started last year, using React Router 2, and this is my current configuration for routing using React Router 2.

```
const routes = (
  <Router>
    <Route path="/" component={Home}/>
    <Route path="about" component={About}/>
    <Route path="work" component={Work}/>
    <Route path="contact" component={Contact}/>
    <Route path="project/:project" component={ProjectPage}/>
    <Route path="tictactoe/demo" component={TicTacToePage}/>
    <Route path="blog/:blogid" component={BlogPage}/>
    <Route path="*" component={NotFoundPage}/>
  </Router>
);

export default routes;
```

Each of the project pages details are stored in JSON on the server, and my Project page is as follows:

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    const url = this.props.routeParams.project;
    const Project = Data.find(page => page.name === url);
    if (Project !== undefined) {
      return (
        <Layout>
          <div className="page-container">
            <h1> { Project.title } </h1>
          </div>
        </Layout>
      )
    } else {
      return (
        <Layout> 
          <NotFoundPage />
        </Layout>
      )
    }
  }
}

export default App;
```

I'm experiencing a little slower than normal loading speeds when loading the project pages, of course due to the lookup needed in the Data.json file:

```
export const Data = [
  {id: 0, name: 'tictactoe', title: 'Coding an unbeatable TicTacToe opponent', demo: 'tictactoe/demo'}
]
```

Is this the best way of providing more dynamic routing based on server side with React? I'm very new to React, and am just trying to work this all out! Changing between standard pages is incredibly quick, but I see a white screen flash when I load a project page.

EDIT: I have tried to add a promise request in my componentWillMount:

```
componentWillMount() {
    const url = this.props.routeParams.project;
    let promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      let response = Data.find(page => page.name === url);
      resolve(response);
    }).then(project => {
      this.setState({
        project: project,
      }, () => {
        console.log("Project loaded: ");
        console.log(project.title);
      });
    });
  }
```

Yet I still see the same white screen flash and the same loading speeds for the project page.

Comment: If data is too big and makes your application slower, what do you want to do against this?

Comment: I was just wondering if anyone knew a better way for the routing or loading the content, if not then that's absolutely fine!

Comment: You can make a fadeout effect while loading the data.  By the way, how big is your JSON file? The example you exposed isn't big enough to have an impact.

Comment: My data won't be large at all, only a few lines! But I want to potentially improve on the parts around searching for the data, like the answer mentioned I'm not trying to use #componentDidMount

Comment: Then I don't see why you say this: _of course due to the lookup needed in the Data.json_. Filter an small array is a really fast operation.

Comment: Sorry I think I badly worded the question. My problem is that when I go to the new project page, (my website background is a dark colour) the screen flashes white as it's loading (I think). I wanted to mainly stop the screen flashing white! Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151891/discussion-between-lilezek-and-olly).

Answer (score 2):

I don't think its the best way to fetch all your data and filter them client-side, what about making the promise request inside your (componentWillMount) so you fetch just one project (from routing variable), and you may display some loader till the promise is resolved.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I've attempted to implement what you mean, however it doesn't seem to have affected anything much at all. I have tried both componentDid and WillMount, would you mind checking the promise I am attempting if it is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

In the unlikely chance anyone stumbles across the same issue, I found that a "target=" attribute in my  tag caused this issue. It didn't even open up a new tab, simply caused the page to flash white as if to reload.

The issue wasn't with the page, but the link toward the page.